# RGB values in Landsat 8 image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, landsat-8

When I click on "information" of a Landsat 8 image (bands 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7 are combined), I get three RGB values: 10928, 10137 and 10265 respectively.

What do these values mean?

They don't correspond to the usual 0-255 RGB values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the Landsat 8 images are provided in 16 bit instead of 8 bit in previous Landsat images. It is stated clearly in [USGS-Landsat-8](https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-8):

> These sensors both provide improved signal-to-noise (SNR) radiometric
>   performance quantized over a 12-bit dynamic range. (This translates
>   into 4096 potential grey levels in an image compared with only 256
>   grey levels in previous 8-bit instruments.) Improved signal to noise
>   performance enable better characterization of land cover state and
>   condition. **Products are delivered as 16-bit images** (scaled to 55,000
>   grey levels).

Here is another information using [How does Landsat 8's 12-bit data improve data products?](https://landsat.usgs.gov/how-does-landsat-8s-12-bit-data-improve-data-products), and the answer is:

> Landsat 8’s Operational Land Imager (OLI) and Thermal Infrared Sensor
>   (TIRS) sensors provide improved signal-to-noise (SNR) radiometric
>   performance quantized over a 12-bit dynamic range.
>
> This translates into 4096 potential grey levels, compared with only
>   256 grey levels in previous 8-bit instruments. Improved signal to
>   noise performance enables improved characterization of land cover
>   state and condition.
>
> **The 12-bit data are scaled to 16-bit integers and delivered in the
>   Level-1 data products**. Products are scaled to 55,000 grey levels, and
>   can be rescaled to the Top of Atmosphere (TOA) reflectance and/or
>   radiance using radiometric rescaling coefficients provided in the
>   product metadata file (MTL file).

Comment: Then, I have to convert this image to a 8-bit .tiff ?

Comment: The idea for 16 bit image to get a better quality data and it is much better compared to 8-bit. It is better not to convert to 8-bit depth unless you have a specific reason for that.

Comment: Then, a supervised classification will be better with this 16 bit landsat8 image than a 8 bit one.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. May I ask youtoo, which source of information can I look at in order to know about the LiDAR RGB parameters?

Comment: You need to ask a new question to ask for LiDAR RGB parameters. But the question should be a focused question to avoid the closure of your question.